# Order dataframe by column of another dataframe

Tags: r

Consider the following `df`: `df1 <-data.frame('GID'=c('GID1','GID3','GID2','GID1','GID2'), 'Sequence'= c(4,7,6,2,3))` `df2  <-  data.frame('GID' = c('GID3','GID1','GID2','GID1','GID2'),'Trial'=c('SA1','SA5','ES4','ES3','ES9'))`

I want to order `df1` by the column `df2$GID` such that I could `cbind` the `df2$Trial` column into `df1`. I know `match` can do that but `match` only finds the first occurrence of values and I have repeated values. Thus I'm confused on the way to do that as this is a subset of a large `data.frame`.

Comment: You have duplicates in both datasets for column 'GID'  May need to create a sequence column

Comment: create a sequence column for df2 and then ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using `match` this way: `df1 <- df1[match(df2$GID, df1$GID),]` (make sure to review the results)?

```
 GID Sequence
2   GID3        7
1   GID1        4
3   GID2        6
1.1 GID1        4
3.1 GID2        6
```

Do you want to get the cartesian product of GID, Sequence and Trial?

Also, could there be any GID of df2 that is not present in df1 and how would you like to handle that?

Do you have any data acting as a "key", identifying uniquely each entry?

Comment: No, I don't need the cartesian product.

Comment: No, I don't need the cartesian product. the df1 was first shorter than df2. df1 had no repeated values while df2 had. Then I expanded df1 as follows `df1[df2$GID,]`. Thus all GID from df2 are present now in df1 and replicated by df2. What identifies uniquely each GID is the combination of the two columns of df2 e.g: `df2$GID,df2$Trial`. Such combination is unique and is in fact what I want to transfer to df1.

Comment: Actually, `df1`, does not have each value of GID matched to a unique value of Sequence, thus I can't understand how it doesn't have or shouldn't have replicates.

Comment: actually is the GID column of df2 that has a unique Trial. So df2 dataframe has duplicated GIDs but unique Trial numbers for the duplicated GIDs . Do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: This can't be true, since e.g. GID1 is matched to both SA5 and ES3 trials. Do you mean that the "key" of df2, is the Trial and a single Trial value can only be matched to one GID value?

Comment: If that is the case, I can't get what your final data-frame should be, since you don't want the cartesian product. I suggest that you edit your question and provide your initial data, without any processing, and their restrictions / properties and show what your final data-frame should be.